# Select2.js v4.0: how set the default selected value with a local array data source?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

By using [select2.js](https://select2.github.io/) v4  plugin , how set the default selected value when I use a local array data for source?

for example with this code

```
var data_names = [{
  id: 0,
  text: "Henri",
}, {
  id: 1,
  text: "John",
}, {
  id: 2,
  text: "Victor",
}, {
  id: 3,
  text: "Marie",
}];

$('select').select2({
  data: data_names,
});
```

How set id 3 as the default selected value?

Comment: $("#id").select2().select2("val", 'oneofthevaluehere');

Comment: As of v4.1 just do {id: 3, text: "Marie", selected: true}.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$('.select').select2({
        data: data_names,
    }).select2("val",3);
```

Answer (score 5):

this worked for me with V4.0.3

```
$('.select').select2({
    data: data_names,
})
$('select').val(3);
$('select').trigger('change.select2');
```

Comment: This is the correct answer for v4.  More compactly you can write `$('.select').val(3).trigger('change')`. Use `trigger('change.select2')` to notify only Select2 of the change. See http://select2.github.io/options.html#what-events-does-select2-listen-for

Answer (score 4):

It is better you send another attribute (selected in my case below) for select and use it to set the default value. I did something like below -

```
var data_names = [{
  id: 0,
  text: "Henri",
}, {
  id: 1,
  text: "John",
}, {
  id: 2,
  text: "Victor",
}, {
  id: 3,
  text: "Marie",
  selected: true
}];
```

then do

```
            $(".select").select2({
                data : data_names
            });
            data_names.forEach(function(name){
                if(name.selected) { 
                   $(".select").select2('val',name.id);
                }
            });
```

Comment: This is the correct answer for version 4.1. All you need is "selected: true" on your data element, should not trigger any events or call an API method.

Answer (score 2):

It's worked for me.

`$('#select').select2({data: data_names}).val(3).trigger('change')`